# Is it possible to measure "CPU time" an app uses?

Tags: android, performance, cpu-usage

I'm writing an Android app that delivers statistics on the device it is installed on, and want to know if it is possible to determine the following metric.

Time the CPU has spent servicing a specific process.  The device I am testing on has a 4 core processor, and I would like to get time spent regardless of weather the process in question is in the foreground or background.  Using top gives you the % of the CPU a process occupies, is there a way to determine time (in seconds or clock cycles)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `ps` command. It has format specifiers, i.e. fields/columns that provide CPU and wall time.

For example cputime for Android:

```
ps -x

will yield something that looks like this
u0_a16    18214 17002 743644 18104 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.location.fused (u:10, s:13)
```

where u:10 and s:13 stand for time the CPU has spent on the processes (source : http://codeseekah.com/2012/10/21/android-shell-tricks-ps/)

I've made a Linux script for collecting system stats which you can check here: https://gist.github.com/izmailoff/8923008.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Aleksey, but when I run ps from the terminal I have set up, I'm not getting cputime (sadly).  It looks like the command is stripped down for the purposes of Android.  This is what I see when I run it.  

 shell@android:/sys/class $ ps    
 USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME

Comment: Lunchtime for me, so I'll be back soon, but before I go, I found a potentially useful link for anyone else wondering.  According to http://codeseekah.com/2012/10/21/android-shell-tricks-ps/ you can use "ps -x" to get user and system time of a process

Comment: I don't have access to android now but maybe this info would be available in /proc/<pid>

Comment: Is it possible to get a cpu time that is greater than 
(#cores)*(elapsed wall time)?

Comment: I don't know. Technically it should not be possible, but sometimes these things don't add up just because of inaccuracies. BTW it's number of threads, not cores.

Answer (score 0):

This is something for which `gprof` could actually be a good tool, if you can use it.

It only samples CPU time, and its samples are typically every 10 milliseconds.

So, see how many samples it gets, regardless of what functions they fall in, multiply by 10, and that's how many milliseconds your program used.